# How to compile example from tcolorbox documentation with current TL (2019)?

Tags: errors, color, tcolorbox, texlive-2019

The definition for `marker` below is from `tcolorbox.doc.s_main.sty`. With earlier versions of Texlive (and `tcolorbox`), this worked fine, but with updated Texlive, it does not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,tikz,tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,hooks}
\makeatletter
% from tcolorbox.doc.s_main.sty
\newtcolorbox{marker}[1][]{enhanced,
  before skip=2mm,after skip=3mm,
  boxrule=0.4pt,left=5mm,right=2mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,
  colback=yellow!50,
  colframe=yellow!20!black,
  sharp corners,rounded corners=southeast,arc is angular,arc=3mm,
  underlay={%
    \path[fill=tcbcol@back!80!black] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);
    \path[draw=tcbcol@frame,shorten <=-0.05mm,shorten >=-0.05mm] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);
    \path[fill=yellow!50!black,draw=none] (interior.south west) rectangle node[white]{\Huge\bfseries !} ([xshift=4mm]interior.north west);
    },
  drop fuzzy shadow,#1}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{marker}
  Hylo!
\end{marker}

\end{document}
```

This gives the following error

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `tcbcol@back'.

See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.34 \end{marker}

?
```

Why are `tcbcol@back` and `tcbcol@frame` undefined if they work in the code for the package's documentation? Alternatively, what are the correct names for the colours which were `tcbcol@back` and `tcbcol@frame`?

My version of `tcolorbox` is 2019-09-19.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `@` from the color names. Why? Because now in `tcolorbox.sty` one finds

```
colback/.colorlet=tcbcolback,
colframe/.colorlet=tcbcolframe,
```

and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,tikz,tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,hooks}
% from tcolorbox.doc.s_main.sty
\newtcolorbox{marker}[1][]{enhanced,
  before skip=2mm,after skip=3mm,
  boxrule=0.4pt,left=5mm,right=2mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,
  colback=yellow!50,
  colframe=yellow!20!black,
  sharp corners,rounded corners=southeast,arc is angular,arc=3mm,
  underlay={%
    \path[fill=tcbcolback!80!black] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);
    \path[draw=tcbcolframe,shorten <=-0.05mm,shorten >=-0.05mm] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);
    \path[fill=yellow!50!black,draw=none] (interior.south west) rectangle node[white]{\Huge\bfseries !} ([xshift=4mm]interior.north west);
    },
  drop fuzzy shadow,#1}


\begin{document}
\begin{marker}
  Hylo!
\end{marker}
```

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/82

Comment: @cfr OK........

Comment: Bug was in my symbolic links and not `tcolorbox` :(.

Comment: @cfr Both in the question and in the answer we were careful enough not to specify the versions... ;-)

Comment: I put the version of `tcolorbox` in the question?